# base href question bypass for one part?

Tags: php, html, href, radix

Hi all am in a pickle :P

All my code is working fine apart from one small part

```
<body> 
 <?=$loginBar?>
<div id="headerMover">
```

Is there anyway I can warp the

```
<?=$loginBar?>
```

Only, In a base href or something like that?
all the other code in my file runs at gallery.domain.com
and the login part has to be forums.domain.com

I tested this by adding a "base" to the top and it worked for the login part but there rest did not.

So I need to "wrap" or something the same

Cheers

Comment: Shoot do you know if there is any other "easy (because me php is not great :P) way" Thanks

Comment: I think there is no way except prefixing every link in the login bar with the server address.

Comment: Ah all the links are from my forum "software" so that can't be done hmmm

Comment: You'll have to rewrite the links in the login bar then - a simple `str_replace()` *might* do if it's not too complex

Comment: Holysmokes this is way "too much for my skill level" I thought there would of been a easy way hehe (here I was dreaming). oh well thanks alot Pekka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to have multiple `base` tags on the same page. From the [MDC docs:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/base)

> Must have a start tag, and must not have an end tag

You'll have to use absolute URLs in your header.

Comment: I see.. I don't have any base atm, I just wanted to "find" a way to get the <?=$loginBar?> to run from an other url if that could be done (p.s nice rep you got there :P)

Comment: Well after trying all morning am still unable to do it
If you have time this is the "main" part of my code http://pastebin.com/LU2zuZNN and do you have any more ideas? Thanks alot for your help

Comment: @Vodka too much code :) Can you show an example of what kind of links `$loginBar` contains, in a separate Codepad? I can show you the correct str_replace method then

Comment: The links are pulled from my forum software Core but this is an example of one of the templates (where the links are) http://pastebin.com/BhcTB7Gk and this is an image (if needed) http://imgvk.com/?di=413075412303 Thanks lot Sir

Comment: @Vodka can you show what the final, generated links look like in your browser?

Comment: @Vodka this should add a host name to every URL: `<? echo str_replace("href=\"", "href=\"http://www.domain.com/", $loginBar); ?>` use that instead of `<?=$loginBar?>`

Comment: Thanks alot I have a 2nd page witch is only $loginBar would I replace it the same way? Cheers again

Comment: @Vodkaholic hard to tell - maybe just try and see what happens

Comment: There seems to be some other mistake -  otherwise the `?>` wouldn't show. Can you double-check?